# Solving environment: - Killed in conda

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

Hi I'm trying to create a new environment in conda, and I have created it with
`conda create -n test python=3.9`

However, when I try to install torch and torchvision with

`conda install pytorch=1.13.0 torchvision pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

The environment gets stuck on solving environment, and eventually gets killed.

I tried to update conda, and make new conda environments to solve this, but it won't do the trick. I have to use python 3.9 to use the python3d package, so other python versions won't solve the problem. What should I do??

Comment: which GPU and NVIDIA driver do you have? For pytorch 1.13.0 on cuda 11.6, you need GPU with computability between 3.5 and 8.7, and nvidia driver at least v450 on linux or v452 on windows.

Comment: you should try `conda activate envname` before installing, to force the desired enviroment to be the one to get things installed, check the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)

Comment: Use Mamba and give all the packages at creation time rather than doing ad hoc installs after creating. If it’s a bunch of stuff, then use YAML - it’s better practice generally.

Comment: I just used pip to install, I had a problem with conda in my GPU. Thanks for your help!!